# flurry - how to view events on a single session?

Tags: android, flurry

I thought it would be straightforward on their dashboard or maybe it's just me.  How can I view the events that took place in a single session?  The sessions on the Flurry Classic dashboard are not clickable.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: if flurry is not related to programming and we're not supposed to ask questions about flurry here, then tell me how come stackoverflow allows a question to be tagged/labeled as flurry??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

events -> event Logs gets there for me.

Finding a Secific one if a user has reported an issue can be a pain if you have a lot comming in best to find out the phone make and time.